# How to work with generics and Class<T> class in java

Tags: java, generics

I have my custom `public class Example` in the package `com.classes`.

**1. How can I get `Class<Example> intance1` and `Class<Example[]> instance2`?**

I can use `Class classInstance = Class.forName("com.classes.Example");`

But In this case I recieve **raw type** Class.

*2. Is it impossible* to create **`Class<Example[]> from Class<Example>`** instance, **right**?

Comment: Can't you use the class literal for Example? So      Class<Example> intance1 = Example.class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question, use a class literal, which is the class name followed by `.class`.

```
Class<Example> c = Example.class;
```

For your second question, I don't see any method in the `Class` class of retrieving the `Class` object for the array of the same type, e.g. no way to get a `Class<Example[]>` from a `Class<Example>`.  But you can still use a class literal to get it directly.

```
Class<Example[]> c = Example[].class;
```

However, it appears that you can get the `Class` object for the component type of the class representing an array, i.e. the reverse of what you want, but it returns a `Class<?>`.

```
Class<?> c = Example[].class.getComponentType();
```

Comment: You can do `Class<?> arrayClass = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Example.class, 0).getClass();`. The temporary zero-element array is negligible compared to the reflective objects. In general array classes could be arrays of primitives. Adding a ton of additional methods for special cases wouldn't be that useful as the point is it's a hacky API for unknown types.